# Removing all spaces in a string

Tags: vb.net

Is there any function in vb.net that removes all spaces in a string.
I mean a string like ' What is this' should be 'Whatisthis'

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [String.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

```
Dim s As String = " What is this"
s = s.Replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anything like Trim for the said purpose?

Comment: Yes, the aptly-named [String.Trim()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx), but it only removes spaces at the start and the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use String.Replace:

```
Dim str As String = " What is this"
str = str.Replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: `str.Replace` cannot modify the original string, therefore your code wouldn't have any effect. Use `str=str.Replace(" ","")` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have used `str=str.Replace("&nbsp","")` with great success.

However, `str=str.Replace(" ","")` has not worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Using `String.Replace`:

```
Dim Test As String = "Hello Hi"
Test = Test.Replace(" ", String.Empty)
```