# Trim function in C#

Tags: c#, string, c#-2.0, trim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing all spaces in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126934/removing-all-spaces-in-a-string)

Hi,

```
    // Input string
    string st = "  This is an example string. ";

    // Call Trim instance method.
    // This returns a new string copy.
    st = st.Trim();

    // output 
    "This is an example string."
```

How can I out put

```
"Thisisanexamplestring."
```

I want to remove all the blanks between the whole sentence. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trim does only remove characters at the start and end of a string. You want to replace all occurrences of space. Use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.string.replace%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for this:

```
st = st.Replace(" ", string.Empty); // Thisisanexamplestring.
```

Note that String.Trim is not needed since we replace all instances of space.